# Recording Skating

Tags: field-recording, sfx

Hey All! I'm working on a wonderful animated Christmas Special that has lots of hockey being played. While I've got loads of library stuff, I'm arranging some time with skaters and a rink to do some custom stuff to add some zing (love it when I have the time and $$ to do that!). Has anyone in the collective done any of this? Any suggestions? Unusual mic choices? I have a plan, but I'm always open to ideas!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[This might provide some ideas.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czaFPtQZE9U)

Comment: Justin, that's great! I think I might have to go watch Miracle again, just to get some inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Hire a lav with extra wind protection and mount it onto one of the boots.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the rob nokes stuff Justin linked to, I'd say be sure to get your skater to go as hard as possible during the takes.  Performance matters in stuff like this, and you'll have to direct him like an actor.

Also, skating rinks are very reverberant.  That's certainly authentic to the sound, but be aware that having too much verb baked into the recordings will limit how up front you can push the sounds in the final mix.

As such, tight miking is probably best.

Bring wind protection for swinging that mic around as well.

Answer (score 0):

To add your question, I'd be curious if anyone has attempted to foley ice skate movements with props in a traditional foley booth.

I had a similar project a year or so ago- VERY low budget animation.  Unfortunately I had to cut in library effects because there was NO money, and I live in Los Angeles.  It was passable but I would have loved to record some fresh material.  This is pretty high up on my list of things to record.